# Xamarin forms refresh listview to tap an item many times

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin, I have a listview with Items "A","B","C".

When I click on one Item I got a display alert that says Item "A was tapped".
When I click again on Item A nothing happen but something happens if I tap the Item "B" or "C" ("B was tapped" or "C was tapped")

My question is, how can refresh my listview in order to tap waterver I want the Item A ?

I have used `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>  });` but it is not helping

Here is the code :

```
 public void ListviewLanguageRefresh1()
        {

       
                var dictionary = keys.Zip(values, (k, v) => new { Key = k, Value = v })
                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);  // contaning Items A,B,C

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {

                //Trying to refresh the listview
                ListViewlingueelanguages.ItemsSource = dictionary;
            });

           
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity)

- ItemSelected fires when a **new item** is selected.
- ItemTapped fires when an item is tapped.

You didn't actually post the code you are using for "tapped" but I assume you are using `ItemSelected`.  You can either switch to `ItemTapped`, or clear the `SelectedItem`property in your `ItemSelected` handler